# Generic increment function in Idris2

Tags: idris

Just learning Idris 2 and trying to implement a generic increment function that could work with any Real/Integer numbers, as far as I know Num type should cover Fractional numbers so I thought that this could satisfy the definition requirements:

```
inc : Num ty => ty -> ty
inc x = x + 1
```

but when running this with Double numbers it fails.

```
Main> inc 2.3
Error: Can't find an implementation for FromDouble Integer.

(Interactive):1:5--1:8
 1 | inc 2.3
```

Is there a way to extend Num to do this or does exist another type that could help me?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
inc : Num ty => ty -> ty
inc x = x + 1

x : Double
x = inc 2.3
```

Comment: what does this mean? does it mean that the function is correctly defined to deal with any numeric type and its just that the REPL needs the type definition?
I could make it work in the REPL doing this:
`the Double $ inc 3.3` I wonder if there is a less verbose way, but I see in your example that in an actual program it wouldn't be needed, would you mind explain this a bit, please?